# How to extend the UserManager with new functionality in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity

I am working on ASP.NET Core 6.0. On the `Registration.cshtml` page, I have added a new field called `UserCreatedUserName`. The `UserCreatedUserName` data is not an email, it's just a unique string entered by the user.

I have created a new `ApplicationUser` derived from `IdentityUser` with this new field and is saved successfully in the `AspNetUser` table. Now, I want to get the user queried by this new field.

For example, the `UserManager` class has a method `_userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email)`. I want to create a similar method to get the user by `UserCreatedUserName`, say `_userManager.FindByUserCreatedUserNameAsync(UserCreatedUserName)`. I am new to identity and please let me know how to extend the `UserManager` class with this new method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extend UserManager to include a search by custom field ASP.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748576/extend-usermanager-to-include-a-search-by-custom-field-asp-net-core)

Comment: I tried that solution. But I am getting, "InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager'

Comment: @Massey that sounds more like a problem with registration to DI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the extension methods and also reproduced the error. After all, I found there's no problem with these methods. It is just because there's some default partial pages such as `_LoginPartial.cshtml` has some code still using `IdentityUser`. 
After changing this part, everything works.

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager   //Need change to ApplicationUser
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager      //Need change to ApplicationUser
...
```

Comment: I went ahead and replaced all <IdentityUser> to <ApplicationUser>. There were so many places I had to change. On some cshtml pages, I had to include this line: @using <MyNamespace>.Models.Model to include the ApplicationUser namespace. Then the extension method worked without any issues.